# What is a mercantile court?

Tags: england-and-wales, court, judiciary

Another answer cites the Birmingham mercantile court. I've never heard of a mercantile court before despite having researched the English court system before. What is this court and where does it fit into the overall system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Circuit Commercial (Mercantile) Court Guide](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/957751/ccc-guide-eng.pdf):

> The Circuit Commercial Courts (formerly the Mercantile Courts) operate in eight regional
> centres throughout England and Wales as part of the Queens [King's] Bench Division of the High Court. They
> decide business disputes of all kinds apart from those which, because of their size, value or
> complexity, will be dealt with by the Commercial Court. As well as large cases, the Circuit
> Commercial Courts decide smaller disputes and recognise the importance of these, particularly to
> small and medium sized businesses. They form part of the Business and Property Courts of England
> and Wales.

More info:

- [Circuit Commercial Courts](https://www.judiciary.uk/courts-and-tribunals/business-and-property-courts/commercial-court/circuit-commercial-courts/)
- [FAQ](https://www.judiciary.uk/courts-and-tribunals/business-and-property-courts/commercial-court/circuit-commercial-courts/circuit-commercial-court-faqs/)
- [The Birmingham Circuit Commercial Court](https://www.judiciary.uk/courts-and-tribunals/business-and-property-courts/commercial-court/circuit-commercial-courts/birmingham-circuit-commercial-court/)